# Invalid Account Discriminator downloading Metaplex Collections

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I updated from anchor 0.17 to version 0.24, and since then, fetching a collection account fails with an anchor error like:
 `Error: Invalid account discriminator`

This is my code

```
export const getCollectionPDA = async (candyMachineAddress: string): Promise<anchor.web3.PublicKey> => {
    return (
        await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [Buffer.from("collection"), new PublicKey(candyMachineAddress).toBuffer()],
            new PublicKey(CANDY_MACHINE_PROGRAM_V2)
        )
    )[0];
};

const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, getmywallet(), {
       preflightCommitment: "finalized",
       commitment: "finalized",
});

const idl = await Program.fetchIdl(CANDY_MACHINE_PROGRAM_V2, provider);
const anchorProgram = new Program(idl, CANDY_MACHINE_PROGRAM_V2, provider);

const candyMachineId = "63gzhYWxJ4Yfc5QahLxV6NChSjJZNWW93Sy9CHz8YkCe";
const collectionPDA = await getCollectionPDA(candyMachineId);
const collectionPDAAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(collectionPDA);

const collectionData = await anchorProgram.account.collectionPda.fetch(new PublicKey(collectionPDA.toString()));
```

I wonder what's going on here. Perhaps the Collection account struct has been updated and the blockchain contains old structs? And only recently anchor started checking for that?